# Drawing graphics on canvas in node-js/Express

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to draw a chart on canvas element. My Jade file contains following:

```
div
   canvas
```

In my index.js file in node.js web application, I tried the following:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)";
height = canvas.height;
width = canvas.width;
context.moveTo(0, 0);
context.lineTo(width, height);
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.stroke();
```

However, it fails to recognize "document". My question is how do I obtain the reference to "canvas" in my .js file? Note that the actual chart would be more complex than the simple line drawing code shown above for brevity. The data for the chart is generated in index.js file at the server end. So the chart will be created on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NodeJS cannot get a reference to the users browser to draw on the displayed page. Although it is Javascript, NodeJS executes on the server side. The same code will have to be written within your HTML page.

If your drawing needs some data to come from the backend NodeJS logic, then the page Javascript will have to invoke your NodeJS services to fetch the relevant data.

Comment: I tried writing the same code in my index.js file as follows:res.render('chart');
        console.log("drawing chart");
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.beginPath(); It gives me error on "document"

Comment: I also tried adding the code     - var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
in my jade file. It gives me error "getContext" undefined

Comment: the `index.js` will be run on the server side so it does not have access to the clients browser. Your web pages have to be separate and at times in an all together different application. Jade is a simple template engine for static content and would not allow the dynamic views. Use the `router` from `express` to route a specific URL to a HTML page you have created and run the code inside the HTML. However the HTML will not get direct access to your NodeJS backend. The same has to be done by hosting NodeJS web services.

Comment: Thank you for your help and guidance. After few experiments based on your guidelines, I experimented and solved the issue by using "script." tag in jade file. This allows me to write Javascript code in jade file. The Jade compiler compiles this into <script> code in HTML. The script is then executed on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

As of August 2021, it's possible to draw on Canvas in Node.js by using
https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas